# How do I trim empty lines using a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string `str`:

```
Normal P start

        feed << feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url => feed_item.user.cloudfront_url(:thumb),
          :full_name => full_name,
          :meta => '',
          :embed_preview => embed_preview,
          :embed_preview_meta => embed_data
        })

Normal P end
```

I want to wrap the code in a `<code><pre>` tag so I have:

```
re = /((?:^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*$(?:\r?\n|\z))+)/
str = str.gsub(re, "<pre><code>\n\\1\n</code></pre>")
```

The problem is that this then yields:

```
Normal P start

<pre><code>

        feed << feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url => feed_item.user.cloudfront_url(:thumb),
          :full_name => full_name,
          :meta => '',
          :embed_preview => embed_preview,
          :embed_preview_meta => embed_data
        })
</code></pre>
Normal P end
```

How can I avoid having blank lines at the top or bottom of the inside `<code>` tag? I also need to make sure that `<code><pre>` and `</code></pre>` are on their own line without anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you're looking for is:

```
Normal P start
<pre><code>
        feed << feed_item.attributes.merge({
          :photo_url => feed_item.user.cloudfront_url(:thumb),
          :full_name => full_name,
          :meta => '',
          :embed_preview => embed_preview,
          :embed_preview_meta => embed_data
        })
</code></pre>
Normal P end
```

Try this:

```
re = /\n*((?:^(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*$(?:\r?\n|\z))+)\n*/
str.gsub!(re, "\n<pre><code>\n\\1</code></pre>")
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be str = str.gsub, or is the gsub! intentional? also, this still ends up having the new line right after the pre code tags

Comment: Hmmm. Your input must be different.  I just ran it again with the input above and although I noticed the last line should have \n after </pre>, it does exactly as advertised.  If you run it multiple times however it will result in multiple sets of tags.

Comment: The blank line after `Normal P start` might be a line of blank spaces causing the error - what if you replace the first `\n*` with `[ \r\n]*`?

Answer (score 0):

Haw about this (after your first gsub)

```
str.gsub!(/\n(\s*\n)+/, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem for a long regular expression. It can be accomplished using that, but fixating on a pattern is clouding the issue:

```
html = <<EOT

    feed << feed_item.attributes.merge({
      :photo_url => feed_item.user.cloudfront_url(:thumb),
      :full_name => full_name,
      :meta => '',
      :embed_preview => embed_preview,
      :embed_preview_meta => embed_data
    })

EOT

code = html.scan(/^ {4}.+/).join("\n")
formatted_code = "\n<pre><code>\n" + code + "\n</code></pre>\n"
puts html.sub(code, formatted_code)
```

Which will output:

```
<pre><code>
    feed << feed_item.attributes.merge({
      :photo_url => feed_item.user.cloudfront_url(:thumb),
      :full_name => full_name,
      :meta => '',
      :embed_preview => embed_preview,
      :embed_preview_meta => embed_data
    })
</code></pre>
```

The code is looking for lines beginning with four space characters and returning them as an array, joining them with carriage returns, then wrapping them with the `<pre><code>` blocks.

This will not work with multiple non-contiguous blocks of indented code but with a little re-engineering it would.

Too often we fixate on a particular solution and think it has to look a certain way. Regular expressions are especially seductive that way. They grow in complexity very quickly, making them hard to maintain.